# What does enc values' meaning in parquet-tools?

Tags: parquet

I use parquet-tools to inspect pages in parquet files, I'm very curious about enc column meaning.
[image]

Like this picture, what does `S`, `R` meaning in this picture?

Answer (score 0):

parquet-tools have been refactored into parquet-cli.

According to [the source code](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-cli/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/cli/Util.java) and assuming you are running the `pages` command:

- The first letter stands for the compression codec: S = SNAPPY, G = GZIP, L = BROTLI, 4 = LZ4, F = LZ4R, Z = ZSTD, _ = uncompressed.
- The second letter stand for [the encodings](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/Compression.md): _ = PLAIN, R = RLE, D = one of the delta encodings.

The `meta` command shows up to 3 letters. The first one is still the compression codec, the second letter documents the encoding of the dictionary if one exists for the column, and the third letter references the encoding of the data of the column.